# Python : Clear the buffer in Twisted Transport write

Tags: python, tcp, twisted, twisted.web

I am developing a chat application in `twisted` in Python. I am using `transport.write()` to write to the TCP stream.

However, sometimes, I notice that the data received at the client side is combined( concatenated).

Is there any way that, we could clear the buffer or flush the data, so that data is received as it is sent and not buffered?

Thanks

Comment: I think it depends on which transport you choose (iirc). However, you could simply add a sequence to split what you're sending on the client.

Comment: See the FAQ that Jean-Paul has linked you to for a full answer, but basically, this is not a problem with Twisted: this is just how TCP connections work.  There's no way to work around it; you just have to parse your data with this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the same as this FAQ item:

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Whyisprotocol.dataReceivedcalledwithonlypartofthedataIcalledtransport.writewith